# Surface area using integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck on the following problem:

Find the surface area of the solid formed be revolving

$$y=\frac{a}{2}\left(e^\frac{x}{a}+e^\frac{{-x}}{a}\right)$$

about the $x$ axis from $x\in[-a,a]$.

Can you please provide a full explanation and working if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a type-o in your function $y=f(x)$? Because it can be written as $y=\frac{a}{2}(2 e^{\frac{x}{a}})=a e^{\frac{x}{a}}$ the way I'm reading it.

Comment: Or maybe it can be construed as $y = e^x$.

Comment: True. I was kind of thinking that after I wrote x/a as exponent. Maybe it was just the x as exponent.

Comment: yes there was a type-o, sorry. I have edited it.

Comment: $\frac{a}{2}\left(  e^{x/a}+e^{-x/a}   \right)$.may be intended.

Comment: Do you mean $a\cosh  \left(\frac xa\right)$?

Comment: You are correct Andre Nicolas.

Comment: Viewing it as $a\cosh(x/a)$ as David Quinn mentioned, will help. If you are not familiar with hyperbolic functions, you will have to notice something cute when you calculate $1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$. You probably have used the same trick in an arclength calculation.

Comment: what is h in this equation?

Comment: Cosh is hyperbolic cosine.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve is described by the function $y = f(x)$, $a \le x \le a$, then the surface area equal to
$$A=2\pi\int_{-a}^a f(x)\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx.$$
In you case, $f(x)=a\cosh\frac{x}{a}$ (it's well-known chain curve or catenary). Then $f'(x)=\sinh\frac{x}{a}$, $\sqrt{1+f'^2}=\cosh{\frac{x}{a}}$, and
$$A=2\pi\int_{-a}^a a\cosh^2\frac xa\,dx=2\pi a\cdot \frac a2 (2+\sinh2)=\pi a^2(2+\sinh2)$$

Comment: How does √1+f'^2=coshx/a?

Comment: @michael, $1 + \sinh^2 x = \cosh^2 x$

Comment: how do you get 2pia.a/2(2+sinh2)?